# Java - Scrolling JPanel with keyboard using Viewport doesn't work

Tags: java, scroll, keyboard, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a little issue with my program, so I ask for your help.

I added a `JScrollPane` in a `JFrame` and in that `JScrollPane` I added a `JPanel`. Scrolling that `JPanel` with my mouse works normally.
[image]

But, in an other script, there's a `while(true)` running, and it detects when I press the keys: W,S,A,D. And if it detect a key press, it uses:

```
mainWorldScrollPane.getViewport().setLocation();
//mainWorldScrollPane is my JScrollPane
```

to scroll the `JPanel` , but the problem is that it does not scroll the `JPanel`, it scrolls the `ViewPort` of the `JScrollPane`.
And this is what I get:
[image]

So, my question is:
Can somebody tell me how do I scroll the `JPanel` with those keys, not the `//JScrollPane's ViewPort`?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"there's a while(true) running, and it detects when I press the keys: W,S,A,D. And if it detect a key press"* ... why? You should be using key bindings (or if you're really stuck, `KeyListener`); `mainWorldScrollPane.getViewport().setLocation()` changes the location of the `JViewport`, which simply contains a clipped view of the component, so changing it's location doesn't scroll the view

Comment: Instead, you should be calling the component's (the view) [`scrollRectToVisible`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible-java.awt.Rectangle-)

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: Oh and by the way, I am using the 'while(true)' to detect and do multiple actions at the same time. So, I want to keep that 'while(true)'. So, Can I do that?

Comment: I have no context, but using a while loop like this is dangerous, as Swing is single threaded and not thread safe

Comment: But, in the `mainStart` class, I used an `ExecutorService executor   = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` and then executed a new `Runnable` to start that `while` loop. So, I should still get rid of that loop, or keep it?

Comment: It's okay, by the way, **Thanks a Lot** , because your answer worked! Now, every think is fine! `JPanel.scrollRectToVisible();` Is working! Thanks!